# Don't output empty list in JAXB (Object to String)?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an object which may contain an empty list. If the list is empty, I would like not to see the tag appearing in the `String` output of my XML. 
However, JAXB is still outputting the empty tag.

My field in class `RemoteEdition.java`:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "dealings")
@XmlElement(name = "dealing")
private List<Dealing> dealings;
```

Desired output when `dealings` is an empty list:

```
<remoteEdition>
</remoteEdition>
```

Actual output:

```
<remoteEdition>
    <dealings/>
</remoteEdition>
```

In Jackson, I would annotate the element with:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private List<Dealing> dealings;
```

Is there an equivalent in JAXB? I can't find any example on the web...
P.s. I've already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36837900/3111149) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve this is to leverage the `beforeMarshal` method. This empty element is only created when the list `dealings` is empty but not null.

So you can set the field to `null` in the `beforeMarshal` method iff the list is empty.

Here is an self contained example:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Root {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "wrapper")
    @XmlElement
    private List<Element> element;

    void beforeMarshal(Marshaller u) {
        if (element != null && element.isEmpty()) {
            element = null;
        }
    }
}

class Element {

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Root jaxbElement = new Root();
    jaxbElement.element = new ArrayList<JaxbNullElementWrapper.Element>();
    context.createMarshaller().marshal(jaxbElement, writer);
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
}
```

Output: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><root/>`